Intellij IDEA doesnt use custom gradle user home
I have configuration in idea ultimate 2024.1.2 (MacOS as system) for gradle:

How you can see - i have overrided path to gradle user home. But that still creates .gradle in user home directory when i opening some of gradle project. Someone can tell me how i can fix this feature ?

Fixed by executing IDEA from shell:
/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea

Thanks to @romanv-jb

Try setting GRADLE_USER_HOME Environmental Variable in your OS (you'll have to restart IDEA for it to take effect).

that's exists: export GRADLE_USER_HOME="/Users/andrzejjankowski/Developing/repository/gradle-cache" (.zshrc). Working well, from console, but not from IDEA.

There is a known issue for macOS, where IDEA may not inherit the correct environment (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-334183/Gradle-issue-in-Intellij-but-works-on-command-line). Try starting IDEA from the Command Prompt directly using "idea" command.
